# Transaction Management (Two Phase commit protocol) in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, distributed-transactions

I have two EJB Applications: A (deployed on Glassfish 2.1) and B (deployed on GlassFish 3.1). Both applications can communicate through Web Services.

I start a transaction in application A and communicate with the application B though Web Services but I get an exception on application B.

I want a single transaction management in Application A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the life-cycle in my opinion.

- Start your transaction on A.
- Send request to B.
- B throws exception.
- Send message back to A with failure since B can communicate back.
- Rollback Transaction on A.

Comment: but how implement in j2EE,When i send a request to B Application,i got exception on B application  failed for activityId 'urn:uuid:4D2-313332363639373734333032342D30'.  Nested exception: 'HTTP Status-Code 404: Not Found - Not Found' 
and A aplication :Registration with durable parent failed: ' coordId=urn:uuid:4D2-313332363639383632383839392D30 partId:2 '

Comment: Without providing any code or context, it would be impossible to understand why you are getting an exception.